# PHP - Making code more efficient/professional

Tags: php

I'm working on an PHP assignment and I basically pretty much made everything work. However with my limited knowledge of PHP, the code looks a little too simple. What it does is to calculate total pay based on the hours and wages entered.

Is there any suggestions you guys can offer to make it better/shorter and much more efficient?

```
<?php
$hours = $_GET ["hours"];
$wages = $_GET ["wages"];

if (empty($hours)) 
{
    echo "Amount of hours worked is required. <br />";
}
if (empty($wages)) 
{
    echo "Employee wage is required. <br />";
}

if (!is_numeric($hours) and ($wages) && !empty ($hours) and ($wages)) 
{
    echo "Please enter numeric numbers only. <br />";
}

if (!empty($hours) and ($wages)) 
{
    if (is_numeric($hours) and ($wages)) 
    {
         if ($hours <= 40) 
         {
        $totalPay = $hours * $wages;
        echo "Your total pay is $ $totalPay";
         }

         if ($hours > 40) 
         {
        $totalPay = ((40 * $wages) + (($hours - 40) * $wages * 1.5));
        echo "Your total pay is $ $totalPay";   
         }
    }
}       
else 
{
    echo "Unable to calculate total pay.";
}
```

?>

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on [codereview.se] :)

Comment: Use proper indentation, it will make it look a lot better

Comment: What's wrong with simple? Oh right, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) now means "Keep It Super Sophisticated".

Comment: Also mixing `and` and `&&` doesn't look good, I'd stick with `&&`

Comment: You have this code in a bunch of places -- `and ($wages)`, but the only thing it does is make sure that $wages is not NULL or 0. It's redundant in a lot of places, and I'm guessing you mean to wrap it with `is_numeric()` or other similar checks. You could organize your code better by doing all the error checking in the first section, and then value calculation in the second section (right now you are checking in both sections). You could also store all error messages in a single variable (e.g. `$errors`), and only continue processing if $errors is empty.

Comment: Amal Murali: I didn't know of Code Review! Will do so the next time. Thanks.
Chevi: Sorry, I was too focused on making it function right! :(
Oswald : I feel that it a lot of the parts are redundant and there's a way to make it even simpler. Thanks for your feedback though!
Kyra : Will do!
@hargobind : That's a really helpful tip! Will definitely check on how I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: @andig, it's good that you're editing, but you reformatted the brace style and in-code spacing of the OP's code. This kind of tidying is too significant a change, imo - let the code in the question reflect the code the OP actually has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it even simpler by implementing a `validate` function

```
function validate($time, $fee)
{
    if(!is_numeric($time) || empty($time)) // ...etc
    {
         return false;
    }

    return true;
} 

if(validate($_GET['hours'], $_GET['wages']))
{
    // do your calculation
}
else
{
    // display error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Kyra! 

I tried using a function to check for errors but it didn't work as it keep showing a blank page. Will try again! :)